# How do I display a response from a POST API when a user is offline?

Tags: android-studio, android-volley, offline-caching, offlineapps, offline-mode

I am getting JSON response from server and I'm displaying it in Listview.
It all works fine when the user has an active internet connection, But when user doesn't have any internet connection the app crashes.

I want to implement a sync function here so that once the data is fetched by user it can even be seen if the user doesn't have an internet connection.

I'm fetching the data using the following code:

```
        {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("param1", paramVal);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(params);
        String url = "https://dummy.com/getDetails";


        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url
                , json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {
                try
                {

                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                    String status = object.getString("status");

                    if (status.equals("200"))
                    {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("arayname");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                           //Some Action Here
                        }
                        setupListview();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check in launcher activity, user device has internet unable or not if internet is unable you can ask to user your interner is unable plese active internet

Comment: That is running away from the problem, not the solution of it

Answer (score 0):

offline mode user can't call api or can't get data from server

Comment: i know that, But I need to show them those data So how do i do it? Any Caching technique?

Comment: you can used local database and store data that, if network is connected you can get data from server and update in local database else you can load data from local database